# CSS focus-within to show label

Tags: html, css

Taking an example from the end of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/How_to_build_custom_form_controls:

```css
.select label {
  display: none;
}

.select:focus-within label {
  display: initial;
}

input:checked + label {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
 <fieldset class="select">
  <legend>Pick a fruit</legend>
      <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="Cherry" id="fruitCherry" checked>
   <label for="fruitCherry">Cherry</label>
      <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="Lemon" id="fruitLemon">
   <label for="fruitLemon">Lemon</label>
      <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="Banana" id="fruitBanana">
   <label for="fruitBanana">Banana</label>
  </fieldset>
```

(I have simplified the example to better illustrate the point). Note how you can click on one of the labels, and since focus is inside the select after that, all labels become visible. However, as soon as you try to click on *label* of another item, the labels disappear before selecting that item, since there is a brief period before the mouse button is released where no element is focused. I assume the the browser only handles the click event when the mouse button is released.

Is there any way to keep the focus while holding down the mouse button as well, without JavaScript? I experienced this on Firefox and Chrome on Linux.

I am also surprised by the fact that it acts differently depending on whether you click-and-hold on the label or the radio button.

Comment: Be aware that your semi-transparent options don't meet accessibility standards for text contrast. There are other, better ways to show selected options in a simplified manner.

Comment: @isherwood thanks, the example is only to illustrate the issue. It's not meant to look pretty or anything

Comment: _“[…] it acts differently depending on whether you click-and-hold on the label or the radio button”_ - this allows you to select the label text, without actually activating the radio button. // Many “CSS-only solutions” look easy to implement at first glance, but they often have issues when it comes to accessibility. A deliberately written script solution that takes care of the edge cases (and what else might be _appropriate_ in relation to the desired functionality, like updating ARIA attributes or stuff like that) is almost always preferable in such regards.

Comment: Why are you looking to do this? Just to know if it's possible? No other reasons?

Comment: I want to see if it is possible. Also to see how it compares in terms of complexity to the javascript solution.

Comment: I edited the question with a more minimal example. I think this is perfectly valid technical, focused question. Whether or not you want to do it like this in practice is another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default `<label>` is not a focusable Element.

When you try to click a label it's as if you're clicking away to remove the focus from what you previously clicked.

In order to make an element focusable we use the `tabindex` attribute with a negative value so it doesn't interfere with the navigation because our sole purpose is to make the element focusable

```css
.select label {
  display: none;
}

.select:focus-within label {
  display: initial;
}

input:checked+label {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="select">
  <legend>Pick a fruit</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="Cherry" id="fruitCherry" checked>
  <label tabindex="-1" for="fruitCherry">Cherry</label>
  <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="Lemon" id="fruitLemon">
  <label tabindex="-1" for="fruitLemon">Lemon</label>
  <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="Banana" id="fruitBanana">
  <label tabindex="-1" for="fruitBanana">Banana</label>
</fieldset>
```